# I want to add a html code inside woo commerce Product title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, title

I have added a html code inside the product title so - on the other products gallery page its showing finely but when we open the product it shows title in html format [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk1An.jpg)

Do you have any idea gow to resolve this

Comment: Provide your code that you have ?

Comment: Actually what i did , my product title is big , so i have used some words in h4 tag and remaining in P tag :  <h4 class="menu_head">Breakfast cookie</h4><p class="menu-info">Whole Oat flour, Rolled oats, apple, carrots, banana, vanilla.</p>